# Spring boot @Decimalmin and @Decimalmax not working in request

Tags: spring, rest, validation, spring-boot

I have a spring boot 2.0.0.M7 app.

I've made a request:

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<Account> getAccountById(@DecimalMin("5") @DecimalMax("6")
                                              @ApiParam(value = "ID of account", required = true)
                                              @PathVariable("customerId") BigDecimal customerId{...}if
```

I've added to my gradle:

```
 compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:6.0.9.Final")
```

but if I submit:

```
http://localhost:8081/v1/accounts/1
```

the validation is not working... it simply continues with the wrong param..

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to validate request then add `@Valid` for request body or  field . Also you can add `@Validated` in controller class.

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<Account> getAccountById(@Valid @DecimalMin("5") @DecimalMax("6")
                                              @ApiParam(value = "ID of account", required = true)
                                              @PathVariable("customerId") BigDecimal customerId{...}if
```